# Flask/Jinja Error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'string'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Basically, when I run my flask program and I submit my web form, I get the following error message:

```
    [2021-11-10 19:12:16,207] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/jed/Dropbox/Code/Python Project/server.py", line 13, in home
    return render_template("results.html", result=result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 757, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/Users/jed/Dropbox/Code/Python Project/templates/results.html", line 18, in template
    {% if data[value] is "T": %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'string'
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2021 19:12:16] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here are all of the files involved:

server.py (server):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from forms import QuizForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "1234-asdf-!@#$-ASDF"


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = QuizForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        result = request.form
        return render_template("results.html", result=result)
    return render_template("quiz.html", form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

forms.py (form class):

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired


class QuizForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("First Name:", validators=[InputRequired()])
    asa = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using ASA (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    sas = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using SAS (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    aaa = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using AAA (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    sss = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using SSS (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    aas = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using AAS (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    ssa = StringField("You can prove a triangle congruent using SSA (T/F):", validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit!")
```

base.html (HTML template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='JavaScript Libraries/jquery-ui-1.13.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='JavaScript Libraries/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='JavaScript Libraries/jquery-ui-1.13.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
    <title>Python Quiz Project</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

quiz.html (form):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="h1t"><h1>Geometry Quiz</h1></div>
    <form id="quiz" action="" method="post">

        <h2 id="desc">This is a quiz/survey about triangle congruence, <br>this form will ask you to provide your name and answer several questions about proving triangles congruent, <br>and will give you your score afterwards.</h2><br>

        <h3>So first off we'll just start of with your first name. <br>What should I call you?</h3><br>
        {{form.name.label}}<br>
        {{form.name(size=30)}}<br><br>

        <h3>Alright, so now that we've got that done with, let's get right into the questions.</h3><br>

        {{form.asa.label}}<br>
        {{form.asa(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.sas.label}}<br>
        {{form.sas(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.aaa.label}}<br>
        {{form.aaa(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.sss.label}}<br>
        {{form.sss(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.aas.label}}<br>
        {{form.aas(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.ssa.label}}<br>
        {{form.ssa(size=30)}}<br><br>

        {{form.submit()}}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

results.html (page after the form, containing results):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Correct Answer</th>
            <th>Your Answer</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        {% for key,value in result.items() %}
            {% if key is asa %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "T": %}
                            1/1
                        {% else: %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key is sas %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key is aaa %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "F" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key is sss %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key is aas %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key is ssa %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{data[key]}}</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                    <td>{{data[value]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if data[value] is "F" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {{% endif %}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I can't seem to understand what the error message is telling me, please help!

Comment: There's an unnecessary `:` inside the `if` block in `results.html` line 18.

Comment: I've tried without it before too, I still get the exact same error. I've just been messing around with line 18 trying to see what might fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `results.html` template you have multiple syntax errors:

1. The `result` variable is an `ImmutableMultiDict` e.g. `[('asa', 'T'), ('sas', 'F'), ('aaa', 'T')]`. Therefore during the iteration the `key` loop variable receives the field's name as a simple string (e.g. `asa`), and the `value` variable will hold the field's value as a string as well (e.g. `T`). You should use these variables, not the undefined `data` variable (you pass the submitted form as `result` not 'data' in the `home` view.
2. The key checking should be done as string comparison. So instead of `{% if key is asa %}` you have to write `{% if key is eq("asa") %}` (where we use the [`eq`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.eq) operator), or simply `{% if key == "asa" %}`.
3. The `{{% endif %}}` is incorrect, just use a single `{}`: `{% endif %}`.

The corrected `results.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Correct Answer</th>
            <th>Your Answer</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        {% for key,value in result.items() %}
            {% if key == "asa" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key == "sas" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key == "aaa" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "F" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key == "sss" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key == "aas" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>T</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "T" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% elif key == "ssa" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if value == "F" %}
                            1/1
                        {% else %}
                            0/1
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```